# How to use lottie with NuxtJS to have hover, click and all functions working?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, lottie

I'm using the '[vue-lottie](https://github.com/chenqingspring/vue-lottie)' package and there's not much information about how to use it.

I got the JSON animations from [Lordicons](https://lordicon.com/) and it shows correctly but I can't make the animation work on hover or click, only loop or static (no animation).

My Component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <lottie
      :options="lottieOptions"
      :width="50"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import lottie from "vue-lottie/src/lottie.vue";
import * as animationData from "~/assets/about.json";

export default {
  components: {
    lottie
  },
  data() {
    return {
      anim: null, // for saving the reference to the animation
      lottieOptions: {
        animationData: animationData.default,
        loop: false,
        autoplay: false,
      }
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleAnimation(anim) {
      this.anim = anim;
    },
    stop() {
      this.anim.stop();
    },
    play() {
      this.anim.play();
    },
    pause() {
      this.anim.pause();
    },
  }
};
</script>
```

And I'm using on the page importing the component only:

```
...

<AboutIcon />

...

<script>

import AboutIcon from "~/components/AboutIcon.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    AboutIcon,
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: The linked package is for Adobe effects essentially (when you do export something). Is Lordincons following the exact same pattern?

Comment: yes. Lottie has the plugin for Ater Effects and the package 'lottie-web' (I tried but couldn't make it work). Lordicon is just a collection of icons with he same look and feel, instead of using random icons from here and there..

Comment: For me, if you do not specifically export from Adobe Effects, your thing will not work because it is probably using some proprietary data formatting (coordinates + time probably).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code sample you provided, you forgot to attach the `@animCreated="handleAnimation"` event.

So `this.anim` is actually always null.

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <lottie
      :options="lottieOptions"
      :width="50"
      @animCreated="handleAnimation"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

Then you just have to set a `@mouseover="play"` to start the animation on hover.